# JavaMail oauth requires full mail scope for sending email via gmail

Tags: oauth, scope, gmail, jakarta-mail

JavaMail oauth requires full mail scope for sending email via gmail.

Used scope "`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`" for authorization.
then get refresh and access token.

Java mail:

```
transport.connect(host, port, username, access_token);
```

Got error:

```
Oauth asks for more
```

After changing scope to "`https://mail.google.com/`" for authorization, it works. But this scope will authorize

```
send, read, delete all emails.
```

This scope is too much, no difference from password authentication.